# Pinniped: Use token instead of client certificate

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed pinniped concierge and configured it with keycloak. When I run `pinniped login oidc ...` command, it returns client certificate and key. But I want token instead of client cert and key. The reason for using token instead of cert is that I want to access kubernetes from browser and the client cert does not work in the browser.

How can I do that?